# Hibernate Validator Not Working With Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I am using hibernate validator to validate a form. However the validator does not seem to be working. Below is the model

```
    package com.wallstreet.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;


@Entity
public class Company {

public static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = { "Company Id", "Share Id",
        "Name", "Primary Industry", "Secondary Industry",
        "Price", "Activity",  "Rise  Probability",
        "Move Amount Proabbility", "Range Percent"};
public static final int NO_COLUMNS = COLUMN_NAMES.length;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "COMPANY_ID")
@NotEmpty
private int id;

@NotEmpty   
@Column(name = "SHARE_ID", unique = true)
private String shareID;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "COMPANY_NAME", unique = true)
private String companyName;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "PRIMARY_INDUSTRY")
private String primaryIndustry;

@Column(name = "SECONDARY_INDUSTRY")
private String secondaryIndustry;

@NotEmpty
@Range(min = 0)
@Column(name = "CURRENT_PRICE")
private double currentPrice;

@Range(min = 0, max=1)
@Column(name = "ACTIVITY")
private double activity;

@Range(min = 0, max=1)
@Column(name = "RISE_PROBABILITY")
private double riseProbability;

@Range(min = 0, max=1)
@Column(name = "MOVE_AMOUNT_PROBABILITY")
private double moveAmountProbability;

@Range(min = 0)
@Column(name = "RANGE_PERCENT")
private double rangePercent;

public Company() {
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getShareID() {
    return shareID;
}

public void setShareID(String shareID) {
    this.shareID = shareID;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public String getPrimaryIndustry() {
    return primaryIndustry;
}

public void setPrimaryIndustry(String primaryIndustry) {
    this.primaryIndustry = primaryIndustry;
}

public String getSecondaryIndustry() {
    return secondaryIndustry;
}

public void setSecondaryIndustry(String secondaryIndustry) {
    this.secondaryIndustry = secondaryIndustry;
}

public double getCurrentPrice() {
    return currentPrice;
}

public void setCurrentPrice(double currentPrice) {
    this.currentPrice = currentPrice;
}

public double getActivity() {
    return activity;
}

public void setActivity(double activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public double getRiseProbability() {
    return riseProbability;
}

public void setRiseProbability(double riseProbability) {
    this.riseProbability = riseProbability;
}

public double getMoveAmountProbability() {
    return moveAmountProbability;
}

public void setMoveAmountProbability(double moveAmountProbability) {
    this.moveAmountProbability = moveAmountProbability;
}

public double getRangePercent() {
    return rangePercent;
}

public void setRangePercent(double rangePercent) {
    this.rangePercent = rangePercent;
}
```

}

Below is my Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="admin/registercompanies.html", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveCompany(@Valid Company company,BindingResult result, SessionStatus status){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println("1");
        return new ModelAndView("admin/company/register");
    }
    else{
        companyService.addCompany(company);
        return new ModelAndView("admin/company/registered");
    }
}
```

1 is not being printed out and the company is being registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have forgotten to declare something in your configuration files. Could you add your dispatcher-servlet configuration file? Here is what mine looks like for reference and my validation works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">



    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" /> 
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dlinx90" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />

    <mvc:interceptors>  
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"/>  
    </mvc:interceptors>  

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"  
        id="localeResolver" /> 

    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"  
        id="messageSource">  
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />  
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i was about to answer my own question when you just did. Thanks a loT!